# Fatal error: Call to undefined function xcache_isset()

Tags: php, xcache

How do I install the XCache extension on Windows + WAMP + PHP 5.3 ?

I copied the extension dll in the extensions directory, and added the line in php.ini, then activated it trough the WAMP interface.

The extension appears to be active, but I still get this error :|

Comment: but I don't see the extensions anywhere inside phpinfo(), it only appears checked in the wamp menu

Comment: Can you check inside `phpinfo()` which php.ini is being used?

Comment: it appears to be the correct one. Shouldn't I get a error or something if the module is not loaded? With other modules I get dll errors

Comment: does the xcache php version need to match my php version? because I downloaded XCache-1.3.2-php-5.3.6-Win32-VC9-x86.zip and I have php 5.3.0 ...

Comment: ok I switched to php 5.3.8 and it gets loaded but now I get a "could not find driver" message when I try to use those functions

Comment: ok the problem as the PDO mysql extension which was not enabled on 5.3.8 :) so it works on php 5.3.8 but not on 5.3.0 :( which sucks because for some reason 5.3.8 is like 15 times slower than 5.3.0 on my system

Comment: If 5.3.8 is running more slowly on your system, it's probably a configuration issue.  I've done extensive performance testing for the PHP Group and Microsoft on the 5.2 and 5.3 branch, and there was no significant difference in transactions per second (i.e. performance) between releases on either branch.

Comment: Obviously, the answer would be to run the latest stable version of PHP (which is currently 5.3.8).  However, 5.4 is already on the second release candidate, so it'll probably be production-ready within the next few weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to successfully load a PHP extension, its PHP API version must match your PHP API version.

Use [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to determine the exact version you have, i.e. PHP API  20090626, and download the right xdebug extension DLL, i.e. open google.com and search "xdebug dll 20090626" (without the quotes).